# How to preview video thumbnails while scrubbing the progress bar in video_player(Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, thumbnails, video-player

I am building and VOD app, and trying to implement Youtube like on scrubbing showing thumbnails images for the relative time frame.

I have generated video thumbnails for every minute of total video length, now is there any way built in already to show these for HLS videos, or I need to build some custom solution for it?
If anyone has worked on this before would like some insights on it.

Comment: Did you work this out? If so can you share your answer?

Comment: Posted an answer @SiddharthAgrawal

Answer (score 0):

This is standard in all players that support preview thumbnails (for scrubbing) in VTT files.

A great player that does this is plyr (plyr.io), but most players do.

See instructions here for how it works: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#preview-thumbnails

If you want to generate them automatically, there's an NPM for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprite-vtt-generator